# Implementing anonymous user voting

Tags: java, javascript, spring, flash, cookies

I am building an anonymous voting system for my web application. My goal is to make a system that each computer (device) can perform 1 vote only. I know the best way to achieve this is not to implement it by using anonymous users but I am not too concerned about building a perfectly secured system.

I have searched about persistent cookies but I have soon realised that cookies are unique for each browsers not for each devices, then average users can easily figure out they can vote again on Chrome after voting on Firefox browser.  I would appreciate if you can give me any suggestions.

What is the best way to build this system?

Comment: Since cookies aren't per machine, what is? IP Addresses and MAC Addresses. And IP Addresses aren't even necessarily (from a server's standpoint)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please suggest me a way to figuring out local IP or MAC addresses in browser environment? I have not found any solutions yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [how to allow only one vote for a rating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810793/how-to-allow-only-one-vote-for-a-rating-system)
@ Mike Sherrill 'Catcall':

There seems to be no practical way to strictly enforce one vote per person on the web.

On computer networks, we often use surrogates for people. Some of them are

- network or application login,
- email address,
- IP address,
- cookies,

and so on. But all of these have problems when it comes to one vote per person.

- For web logins, a person can usually make multiple accounts. (Especially if they're free.)
- Email accounts are free, and many (most?) people now have multiple email accounts.
- IP addresses might work, but only on intranets (implemented with one IP address per computer) with unshared computers (company policy of one person per computer).
- Cookies have the same problems as web logins. (And they can be deleted by the user.)

If a vote is really valuable, some people will go to a lot of trouble to vote twice. But most votes aren't very valuable.

Comment: Votes don't have to be valuable for people to manipulate them. http://gizmodo.com/5968230/how-4chan-made-kim-jong-un-time-readers-man-of-the-year